# When to start Shnayim Mikra for a parsha that is delayed due to Yom Tov?

Tags: passover, shnayim-mikra, parshat-acharei-mot

This year (5782) Acharei Mos won’t be read until a few weeks after Metzora, due to Pesach falling on Shabbos (and outside of Israel on the next Shabbos as well). Do the Poskim discuss whether one may start reading the parsha of Acharei Mos before Pesach, or rather if one should wait until the week it is being read?

Comment: I don't have a source offhand but since Shabbos mincha of metzora they already started acharei mos, that's the point one can begin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Mishna Brurah 285 it seems that one can start Shnayim Mikra once the new parsha was read on shabbos during mincha. See  Shevet HaLevi 10:78 who holds sunday and according to some  from mincha shabbos.

Text of MB:

מיום ראשון ואילך - כיון שמתחילין במנחתא דשבתא לקרות פרשת שבוע הבא נחשב שוב הקורא כקורא עם הציבור וא"כ מה שכתב המחבר מיום ראשון ואילך לאו דוקא הוא:

Text of Shevet Halevi:

[image]